# Endless/infinite scroll type solution with backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, infinite-scroll

I'm toying around with backbone.js and I'm wondering if there is more concise solution for creating an 'endless-scroll' situation for models/collection than the modules I've been looking at (there are several for jquery, probably more for other libraries).

Some searching turned up next to nothing, so I thought I'd ask before getting into trying to build my own solution with backbone, if it something I should build outside a backbone collection, or if someone has attempted something similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [blog post](http://tumbledry.org/2011/05/12/screw_hashbangs_building) landed on my twitter stream recently. Looks like a very nice solution and works well on the [main page](http://tumbledry.org/). From the blog the benefits of this solution are:

> 1. Preserves the back button.
> 2. Does NOT use the hashbang, no matter how happy twitter engineers are with it.
> 3. Gives up on infinitely scrolling if (1) is impossible.
> 4. Progressively enhances: when (3) occurs, the user follows a good ol' hyperlink for more content.

Comment: That is interesting, I'll look into it.

Comment: I just wrote an infinite scroll tutorial also http://backbonetutorials.com/infinite-scrolling/

Comment: The article gives very good points. However, personally I'd say don't freak out about non-js fallbacks http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html

Comment: @albertpeiro Agreed, although historically for the sites I have worked on it was a _requirement_ to support non-js for accessibility reasons and support for screen readers. I believe screen readers are much better at interpreting JavaScript and dynamic pages now.

Answer (score 4):

I found two other resources while researching this myself:

1. https://github.com/joneath/infiniScroll.js
2. http://addyosmani.com/blog/backbone-paginator-new-pagination-components-for-backbone-js/

Answer (score 1):

SlickGrid could be an option if you haven't tried it: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples

Comment: Seems interesting and I've seen it before but seems too heavy for some light uses I want right now.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with Backbone and jQuery waypoints: https://gist.github.com/davidmontoyago/6336612

Answer (score 0):

Following extension should work:
https://github.com/joneath/infiniScroll.js

These may also be useful to load data partially:
http://backplug.io/plugin/Backbone.actAs.Paginatable, 
https://github.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable, https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator.

I prefer searching Backbone extensions here: http://backplug.io.

Answer (score -1):

Another repeated answer: Here is my extension of Backbone.Collection:

```
_.extend Backbone.Collection.prototype,
  options:
    infinitescroll:
      success: $.noop
      error: $.noop
      bufferPx: 40
      scrollPx: 150
      page:
        current: 0
        per: null
      state:
          isDuringAjax: false
          isDone: false
          isInvalid: false
      loading:
        wrapper: 'backbone-infinitescroll-wrapper'
        loadingId: 'backbone-infinitescroll-loading'
        loadingImg: 'loading.gif'
        loadingMsg: '<em>Loading ...</em>'
        finishedMsg: '<em>No more</em>'
        msg: null
        speed: 'fast'

  infinitescroll: (options={})->
    # NOTE: coffeescript cannot deal with nested scope!
    that = @

    _.extend(@options.infinitescroll, options.infinitescroll) if options.infinitescroll

    infinitescroll_options = @options.infinitescroll

    # where we want to place the load message in?
    infinitescroll_options.loading.wrapper = $(infinitescroll_options.loading.wrapper)
    if !infinitescroll_options.loading.msg and infinitescroll_options.loading.wrapper.size() > 0
      infinitescroll_options.loading.msg = $('<div/>', {
        id: infinitescroll_options.loading.loadingId
      }).html('<img alt="'+$(infinitescroll_options.loading.loadingMsg).text()+'" src="' + infinitescroll_options.loading.loadingImg + '" /><div>' + infinitescroll_options.loading.loadingMsg + '</div>')
      infinitescroll_options.loading.msg.appendTo(infinitescroll_options.loading.wrapper).hide()
    else
      infinitescroll_options.loading.msg = null

    fetch_options = _.omit(options, 'infinitescroll')
    infinitescroll_fetch = ()=>
      # mark the XHR request
      infinitescroll_options.state.isDuringAjax = true

      # increase page count
      infinitescroll_options.page.current++

      payload = {
        page: infinitescroll_options.page.current
      }
      payload['limit'] = infinitescroll_options.page.per if infinitescroll_options.page.per isnt null

      _.extend(fetch_options, {
        remove: false
        data: payload
      })

      if infinitescroll_options.loading.msg
        # preload loading.loadingImg
        (new Image()).src = infinitescroll_options.loading.loadingImg if infinitescroll_options.loading.loadingImg

        infinitescroll_options.loading.msg.fadeIn infinitescroll_options.loading.speed, ()->
          that.fetch(fetch_options)
          .success (data, state, jqXHR)=>
            infinitescroll_options.state.isDuringAjax = false
            infinitescroll_options.state.isDone = true if _.size(data) is 0

            infinitescroll_options.loading.msg.fadeOut infinitescroll_options.loading.speed, ()->
              infinitescroll_options.success.call(data, state, jqXHR) if _.isFunction(infinitescroll_options.success)
              return
            return
          .error (data, state, jqXHR)=>
            infinitescroll_options.state.isDuringAjax = false
            infinitescroll_options.state.isInvalid = true

            infinitescroll_options.loading.msg.fadeOut infinitescroll_options.loading.speed, ()->
              infinitescroll_options.error.call(data, state, jqXHR) if _.isFunction(infinitescroll_options.error)
              return
            return
          return

      else
        that.fetch(fetch_options)
        .success (data, state, jqXHR)=>
          infinitescroll_options.state.isDuringAjax = false
          infinitescroll_options.state.isDone = true if _.size(data) is 0

          infinitescroll_options.success.call(data, state, jqXHR) if _.isFunction(infinitescroll_options.success)
          return

        .error (data, state, jqXHR)=>
          infinitescroll_options.state.isDuringAjax = false
          infinitescroll_options.state.isInvalid = true

          infinitescroll_options.error.call(data, state, jqXHR) if _.isFunction(infinitescroll_options.error)
          return
      return

    $(document).scroll ()->
      $doc = $(document)
      isNearBottom = ()->
        bottomPx = 0 + $doc.height() - $doc.scrollTop() - $(window).height()

        # if distance remaining in the scroll (including buffer) is less than expected?
        (bottomPx - infinitescroll_options.bufferPx) < infinitescroll_options.scrollPx

      return if infinitescroll_options.state.isDuringAjax || infinitescroll_options.state.isDone || infinitescroll_options.state.isInvalid || !isNearBottom()

      infinitescroll_fetch()
      return


    infinitescroll_fetch()
    return
```

https://gist.github.com/mcspring/7655861

Comment: You can use the fat arrow => instead of the thin arrow and carry over the outer context to @ or _this